# Jquery Can be Applied on One table but not on multiple tables in nav-pills(bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox, bootstrap-table

Designed 5 tables which will be replaced by the inbuilt nav-pills in bootstrap, but I have a Jquery from bootstrap table to get the current row selection on a modal, it executes only on the active tab-pane of nav-pill and does not work for the others.Any Help.HTML code is too long so its on JSfiddle link-https://jsfiddle.net/Azhar786/d1k411pz/

```js
var $table = $('#table');
$(function() {
  $table.on('click-row.bs.table', function(e, row, $element) {
    $('.success').removeClass('success');
    $($element).addClass('success');
  });
  $('#button').click(function() {
    // bootbox.alert(' The Selected model is: ' + Submit().model);
    bootbox.confirm(' Are You Sure?<br>The Selected model is: ' + Submit().model, function(result) { /* your callback code */
      if (result) {
        console.log("User confirmed dialog");
      } else {
        console.log("User declined dialog");
      }
    });

  })
});

function Submit() {
  var index = $table.find('tr.success').data('index');
  return $table.bootstrapTable('getData')[index];
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#mytabcontent a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).tab('show')

  });

});
```

Comment: it is working only on one table and does not work for the rest of the tables,that is what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML your ids must be unique. You have this declaration twice:

`<table class="table" id="table" data-toggle="table">`

The `id="table"` must be unique for the entire document if you're going to use `jQuery("#table")` to search for it.

Also, your statement `var $table = $('#table');` is executed before the document.ready event is fired. If that part of the DOM isn't ready yet, the search won't return any results. You may want to put all your code within the "$(document).ready(function() { });" to ensure the DOM is complete before you run queries.

This isn't a complete answer but I hope it helps you get on track!